# Laravel cant connect database

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I want to simply connect database of hostinger which I have created.You can see my settings of laravel and hosting name and user name etc in image.

[image]

This is error which I have taken *[PDOException]
  SQLSTATE[HY000] [2005] Unknown MySQL server host 'mysql.hostinger.web.tr' (
  2)  *

Comment: @S.I. How can I access hostinger host.Just take a look down of image .(Not local)

Comment: Have you tried connecting with any mysql tool at that server??? It seems like a server issue

Comment: no Can you check it because I dont know how to

Comment: Maybe is case when name resolving doesn't work on the host. In that case you can try to connect with IP address instead.

Comment: Looks like a host name issue. Not specific to laravel I guess

Comment: i would recommend hiding that information. you just gave the internet your database login details.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This looks like a host problem and not a laravel specific problem. I would contact your host and confirm the hostname you should be using and check that it matches that in your .env file.